# DropdownButton not updated by selecting a value in flutter

Tags: android, flutter

Whenever I try to update the value into the desired one it doesn't change

Here's a snippet of the relevant code:

```
new DropdownButton<String>(
            items: <String>['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'].map((String value) {
              return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: value,
                child: new Text(value),
              );
            }).toList(),
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  value1 = value!;
                });
              }
          )
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is that the name of the variable you're updating in setState is named value1, while the variable you assign to the value parameter in your DropdownMenuItem is named value.

Try using the following code for onChanged:

```
onChanged: (newValue) {
            setState(() {
              value = newValue;
            });
          }
```